# Printing an int member variable of a struct gives wrong value

Tags: c, struct

I have a function that reads data and stores it inside a struct declared in a header, the function reads a string fine, but trying to read a number(`int`) returns a random numeric value.

This is the code that causes problems. The struct inside `functions.h`.

```
 struct stats{
  char name[50];
  int calories;
 }temp_list[50],activities[50],food[50];
```

and the actual function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "functions.h"

void scandata(FILE *file1,FILE *file2,int size,int size2){
    int i;
    file1=fopen("in_activities.txt", "r");
    file2=fopen("in_food.txt","r");

    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        fscanf(file1,"%s",&activities[i].name);
        fscanf(file1,"%d",&activities[i].calories);
    }
    for(i=0;i<size2;i++){
        fscanf(file2,"%s" "%d",&food[i].name,&food[i].calories);

    }
    for(i=0;i<size2;i++){              //test print to see the values
        printf("%s ",&food[i].name);
        printf("-%d",&food[i].calories);
    }

    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);
    return;
}
```

if I print the string it is displayed correctly, but the `int` value does not.

Comment: `Cant call an int`---a are you sure you wanted to write this?

Comment: Minor: Recommend `fscanf(file1,"%49s",activities[i].name);` (wdith and no &)

Answer (score 4):

This

```
printf("-%d", &food[i].calories)
```

prints the memory address of `food[i].calories`. If you want the value, you should do simply

```
printf("-%d", food[i].calories)
```

Comment: and how do i actually print the value of calories?

Comment: Nice. I think you put this point before me. I should (and I will) add the attribute to my answer. :-)

Answer (score 3):

In your code, `i` is *automatic* local variable and next,

```
 food[i].calories=1;
```

`i` is used uninitialised. It invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Apart from that, as rightly mentioned in [ericbn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30804313/2173917), your `printf()` statement is erroneous. Change

```
 printf("-%d",&food[i].calories);   //(TRIES TO) print the address of the variable
                                    //refer Note 5 below for details
```

to

```
printf("-%d",food[i].calories);    //prints the value of the variable
```

That said,

1. Always check for the success of `fopen()`.
2. Always check for the return value of `scanf()` and family to ensure expected *scan* is a success.
3. Never use only *variable* loop for a fixed size array. Always have a check for the MAX index **also**.
4. Always try to length-limit the input, otherwise it may very well cause buffer overflow. Use something like

   ```
   fscanf(file1,"%49s",activities[i].name);  //input limited to 49 chars
   ```
5. To print an address, you'll need `%p` format specifier.

Comment: food[i].calories=1; was a random piece of code i forgot to delete when i posted, its not the problem,  fopen() works, the function scans the strings present inside the file and stores them inside the struct no problem,

Comment: @chux I've added your suggestion to my asnwer itself. :-)

Comment: the contents of the answer, about fopen, etc are about the correct way to write code.   This is because the program(er) has no control over the success/failure of a system function call, therefore, most such system calls, especially those that ask for input or perform file operations should always be checked for success/failure

Comment: @user3629249 Sorry, I did not get your point. You mind elaborating a bit?